# JOIN optimisation using partition key in clickhouse

Tags: sql, distributed-computing, clickhouse

I am looking for a feature similar to affinity colocation in clickhouse - https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/data-modeling/affinity-collocation

Basically , I have 2 different tables , lets call it Employee And Attendance

Employee Table

```
ID   Name
-    -
1    Sankar
2    VM
3    Amal
```

Attendance Table

```
Employee_ID   Date.       isPresent    
-             -           -
1             1/1/2020    True
2             1/1/2020    False
3             1/1/2020    True
```

Now let both tree be MergeTree and I have used ID and Employee_ID as partition key.
This make sure that the records of same employee from both table , always ends up on the same node. It does not go to different tables.

Now , when I do a join based on ID and Employee_ID , I want the following to happen.

1. Go to each node
2. Run join on both the local table
3. Take result from each node and further reduce them to get final result.

I tried global and local distributed JOIN and it seems , they are not using this exactly.
Kindly advice on how to achieve this

Answer (score 0):

> used ID and Employee_ID as partition key

you mean sharding key?

---

So you have 4 tables: Employee_local, Employee, Attendance_local, Attendance

The easiest way to do a local join is to use _local for the right table.

```
from Employee join Attendance_local on ...
```

Another option is

```
set distributed_product_mode='local';

from Employee join (select * frin Attendance) on ...
```

This setting is about subqueries only.

Comment: I tried the above. What the above is doing is , it runs "select * from Attendance_LOCAL" on all the nodes where where Attendance_LOCAL is present , merge results , then run "from Employee_LOCAL join (Take data from _subquery )"
.  What I want is to run Employee_LOCAL and Attendance_LOCAL on each node and merge the final result. More like map reduce

Comment: it seems `distributed_product_mode='local'` is broken now https://github.com/ClickHouse/ClickHouse/issues/25809